# can we use one button for two or more conditions

Tags: android, button, autocompletetextview

I am beginner for android this is my first app so i am getting this much of doubts. Can we use one Button for three or more conditions.I did like this but its not working help me(in this source and destination are two different auto complete textview)

```
enter code here

String[] source ={"Chennai","Hyderabad","Bangalore"};
String[] destination ={"Chennai","Hyderabad","Bangalore"};

 if(source[0].equals("Chennai") &&destination[1].equals("Hyderabad"))
 {
     Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchtrain_button);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
             startActivity(i);
         }
     });

 }
    else if (source[0].equals("Chennai") && destination[2].equals("Bangalore"))
    {
        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchtrain_button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        })
```

Comment: What is not working? Can you be more explicit? Like error or just do nothing?

Comment: The problem here is its not checking the condition and it straight goes to first function and its not moving to second function. What ever condition I give it executes first function and not the other. In short it is not checking the condition. I hope am clear to you If am not clear, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: It executes the first condition because the first condition is true. Did you try making the first condition == false?

Comment: it will be always true because source[0] is always 'Chennai' and destination[1] is always 'Hyderabad'.

Comment: Just delete the `else` keyWord, so your second condition will be checked.

Comment: @Chandra, if you use a `if-else` statement, if the condition is true, it never enters the `else` branch. So, if you have a condition which you want to check nomatter the first (true or false) , don't put it in the `else` branch. Just make two simple `if` statements...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I got a solution from a different user. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont you think you have to check your `autocompletetextview` text instead of your array because your array condition will be true always so it will never going to else condition.

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchtrain_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(yourSourceAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Chennai") && yourDestinationAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Hyderabad")) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(yourSourceAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Chennai") && yourDestinationAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().equals("Bangalore")){
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main3Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you. Its working great. Really thank you. I was working with this for a long time. At last it works. Thank you KDeogharkar. Thanks to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this one

```
    final String[] source ={"Chennai","Hyderabad","Bangalore"};
    final String[] destination ={"Chennai","Hyderabad","Bangalore"};


        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchtrain_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(source[0].equals("Chennai") && destination[1].equals("Hyderabad")) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(source[0].equals("Chennai") && destination[2].equals("Bangalore")){
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main3Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you Sean. Thank you for your fast reply. But unfortunately its a same situation. Even after implementing your codes its the same. It is not checking the if condition. It is showing the mainactivity2.class for all the condition. It is not doing the else part.(If I enter source as chennai and destination as bangalore it executes only mainactivity2 and not mainactivity3 as per the condition). Dont know where the problem is.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe your problem is not the button click, can you post more of your codes here ?

Comment: Thank you. I got a solution with another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create a new OnClickListener() depending of a condition you could implement the listener within activity and handle the click

in your activity declaration:

```
public class ActivityNAme extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Then, find the button and all other views:

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchtrain_button);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And finally implements onClick function:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        ... Handle other buttons ...

        case R.id.searchtrain_button:
            //your code here
            break;

        ...
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you for replying. Its working fine. Thank you.